# Expected spy 'spyName' to have been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a method in component that gets the duplicated object, removes some props and than calls another method to create new object:

```
duplicateObject(obj) {
      delete item.id;
      this.creteNewObject(obj);
}

createNewObject(newObject) {
  //some action
}
```

I try to unit test and create such test

```
it('should call createNewObject method ', async(() => {
    const duplicateSpyObject = spyOn(component, 'duplicateObject').and.callThrough();
    expect(duplicateSpyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

But I get

> Expected spy 'duplicateSpyObject ' to have been called

if I do this way

```
it('should add call createNewObject method ', async(() => {
    const duplicateSpyObject = spyOn(component, 'duplicateObject').and.callThrough();
    component.duplicateObject(newObj);  // <-- add this line
    expect(duplicateSpyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

test is successful, test is only successful if those 2 lines are present. If I remove any of these - test fails.

I cannot see why calling through in spyOn does not call this method and why adding `component.duplicateObject(newObj);` make this test successful while without each other it fails.

Comment: @temp_user what do You mean? I am calling in my test by `callThrough()` ?

Comment: No, you're saying the spy should call through the function instead of mocking it. I highly suggest you take a deeper dive into how jasmine works.